# Symfony2 in subdirectory Alias, assets bundle not working

Tags: apache, symfony, alias, assets

I'm trying to run Symfony2 application from a Apache alias /example-site/

The issue is that some of the assets get prefixed with /example-site/bundles/... while some directly start with /bundles.. and do not include the prefix.

What is the cause?

Answer (score 3):

I have found that the problem was the following:

I was using asset command like this (note the / at the beggining):

```
<img src="{{ asset('/bundles/frontend/images/logo.png') }}" alt="">
```

Changed it to this solved the problem (removing / from beggining):

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/frontend/images/logo.png') }}" alt="">
```

So hope maybe helps someone not to lose hours looking for a solution.

Comment: Yes you have to use relative paths.